# Are channelActive and channelRead guaranteed to be invoked by same thread for specific channel?

Tags: netty

I'm using netty 4.X

Netty in action book mentions that

"All of your ChannelHandlers, which contain your business logic, are guaranteed to be executed by the same Thread for a specific Channel."

I wanted to confirm that  channelActive and channelRead guaranteed to be invoked by same thread for specific channel. I've a use case to initialize a member variable in channelActive  based on the channel. The variable won't be modified further. The variable will be later referenced in  channelRead. If the same thread guarantee is valid i can avoid synchronization for this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all of the methods of the ChannelHandlers are executed by the same thread.